# Nested query in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

there are somethings wrong at

`$this->db->where("Mark_ID,(SELECT Mark_ID FROM mark WHERE Course_ID=$Course_ID && Matric_No=$Matric_No)");`

in my model?any suggestion idea?thank you.

```
 function update_record($Course_ID,$Matric_No)
     {  
         if($Course_ID && $Matric_No != NULL)
         {
         $data = array(
             //'Course_ID' => $this->input->post('Course_ID'),
             'Matric_No' => $this->input->post('Matric_No'),
             'Student_Name' => $this->input->post('Student_Name'),
             'Result_Mark_1' => $this->input->post('Result_Mark_1'),
             'Result_Mark_2' => $this->input->post('Result_Mark_2'),
             'Result_Mark_3' => $this->input->post('Result_Mark_3'),
             'Result_Mark_4' => $this->input->post('Result_Mark_4'),
             'Result_Mark_5' => $this->input->post('Result_Mark_5')

                 );

           $this->db->where("Mark_ID,(SELECT Mark_ID FROM mark WHERE Course_ID=$Course_ID && Matric_No=$Matric_No)");

           $this->db->update('mark', $data);
         }
     }
```

Comment: Why?? You don't have to use the Mark_ID & since you're updating & selecting from the same table adding the conditions directly would serve the same purpose.

Comment: Thank you for reply. The problem is I only have the $Course_ID and $Matric_No, the update require according to the Mark_ID.so,I need to get the Mark_ID first.

Comment: This doesn't mark sense at all, you don't need subQuery for these at all, since it's the same table & you have the keys to use in a normal where statement. It will generate the same effect if you use these directly.

Comment: Something like this should work: $this->db->where(array('Course_ID' => $Course_ID, 'Matric_No' => $Matric_No))->update('mark', $data);

Comment: Sorry,I think too much.It working well. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `IN()` clause

```
$subquery="SELECT Mark_ID FROM mark WHERE Course_ID=$Course_ID && Matric_No=$Matric_No";
$this->db->where("Mark_ID IN($subquery)",null,FALSE);
```

But you are using subquery from same table to update you will face the error of

> you can't specify target table in update query

For this you need to give new alias to your subquery like

```
$subquery="SELECT t.Mark_ID FROM(
           SELECT Mark_ID 
           FROM mark  
           WHERE Course_ID=$Course_ID && Matric_No=$Matric_No
           ) t ";

$this->db->where("Mark_ID IN($subquery)",null,FALSE);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to make your life easier by forgetting about nested queries. If you still want to use nested query, answer posted above is correct. You need to use **IN**

```
function update_record($Course_ID,$Matric_No)
     {  
         if($Course_ID && $Matric_No != NULL)
         {
         $data = array(
             //'Course_ID' => $this->input->post('Course_ID'),
             'Matric_No' => $this->input->post('Matric_No'),
             'Student_Name' => $this->input->post('Student_Name'),
             'Result_Mark_1' => $this->input->post('Result_Mark_1'),
             'Result_Mark_2' => $this->input->post('Result_Mark_2'),
             'Result_Mark_3' => $this->input->post('Result_Mark_3'),
             'Result_Mark_4' => $this->input->post('Result_Mark_4'),
             'Result_Mark_5' => $this->input->post('Result_Mark_5')

                 );

            // pre update query
            $this->db->select('Mark_id');
            $this->db->where('Course_ID', $Course_ID);
            $this->db->where('Matric_No', $Matric_No);
            $tmp_result = $this->db->get();
            $result = $tmp_result->row();
            $mark_id = $result->Mark_id;

            //updation
           $this->db->where("Mark_ID",$mark_id);
           $this->db->update('mark', $data);
         }
     }
```

Comment: Ya,I have used this method before but facing error.My method is do not have $result = $a->row(); and yr suggested method facing error too(near the WHERE condition).

Comment: fixed. my bad. That was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use below code for get your result.

$this->db->select("Mark_id");

$this->db->where("Course_ID",$Course_ID);

$get_id = $this->db->get($this->tbl_user)->row();

after getting mark id simply pass it to below query.

$this->db->where('Mark_id', $get_id->Mark_id);

$this->db->update($this->tbl_user,$data);